# SearchView in activity toolbar and filter to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have given SearchView in activity with custom toolbar and filter data goes to fragment. When I click on the search icon,toolbar size increasing. Navigation bar is used in that activity,may be it is issue?.
It is working with separate activity without navigation bar.vb

Here is my code:
**Activity.xml :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:elevation="5dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    app:contentInsetEnd="5dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="15dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="5dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="15dp"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="15dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_student_details"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_student_details_spinner"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >
        </Spinner>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/admin_image"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Fragament code:**

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
 ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView= 
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_staff_fragment_admin, 
            container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}

    @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    getBaseActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, 
     menu);
    SearchView searchView;
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getBaseActivity(). 
   getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    assert searchManager != null;
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getBaseActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
     SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when query submitted
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when text is changed
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to changes in the `Activity` and send the result to your `Fragment` as your `SearchView` is inside the `Activity` ( in the custom `Toolbar`). One of the problems you may be facing is that the searchview is null when you are calling it.

I recommend doing this through your `ViewModel` if you are using **Android Architecture Components** and the **MVVM** pattern as follows:

1. Listen to changes in your **Activity**

```
// listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
     SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //filter the data in step 2
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter data in step 2
            return false;
        }
    });
```

2. Send the query to your ViewModel function to filter the data

**inside your Activity:**

```
        ...
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //filter the data
            viewModel.filterData(query);
            return false;
        }
        ...
```

**inside your ViewModel:**

```
       public List<String> listOfData = getListOfData();
       public LiveData<List<String>> searchResults = new MutableLiveData(listOfData);

       // filter list of data when query submitted
       public void filterData(String query) {
            //filter outside of your RecyclerView Adapter through your listOfData variable
            searchResults.value = getFilter().filter(query);
       }

       public LiveData<List<String>> getSearchResults() {
            return searchResults;
       }
```

by setting the result on your `LiveData` through `searchResults.value` you can listen to it change directly from your `Fragment`, thus completing the communication between your `Activity` and your `Fragment` `RecyclerView` through this variable in step 3.

3. Observe the `ViewModel` variable inside your `Fragment` & update the Adapter

**inside your Fragment**

```
        override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)


            viewModel.getSearchResults().observe(this, { searchResults->
                Log.w("onActivityCreated()", "new search list received :" +searchResults)
                mAdapter.updateList(searchResults)
                listItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            });

    }
```

With these changes, you're filtering from the Activity `SearchView` and sending the results to the `Fragment RecyclerView` which should work. If you are using another pattern, the important thing is to send the query from your `Activity` to your `Fragment` instead of listening in your `Fragment` only.

If you aren't using these yet, I recommend taking a look at **AAC** with **MVVM**. You can find more info in the [Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java) about these concepts.

Hope this helped, good luck.

Comment: Filtering is not an issue.it is working. Onclick of  Search icon tool bar size increasing.Look wise it is not good.

Comment: I have added screenshot.please check

Comment: Are you receiving the query in `onQueryTextChange` though? If so, and if filtering is working then you may have a problem in your adapter. Otherwise, your problem may be in the way you are getting the query parameter.

Comment: so far working fine.can you please tell me why that toolbar size is increasing?

Comment: From what I can guess, the items in your toolbar may be getting pushed and creating extra height for the toolbar when the `SearchView` is opened.

Comment: Your style/Toolbar could also be the reason if it has any height parameters. Try leaving the Toolbar on its own, with a `SearchView` and see if the height problem is fixed.

Comment: I have fixed it by removing views inside custom toolbar.Thank you for reply panos Gr.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If you want, I would really appreciate if you accept my answer. Thank you.